# How to Draw a Centered Disc Surface in a 3D Cartesian Coordinate System

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

What is the optimal method for drawing a disc surface centered at the origin within a 3D Cartesian coordinate system? The representation should additionally feature a point *P* situated above the disc's center along the *z*-axis. Furthermore, can you draw an infinitesimal area *dA=rdrdθ* using polar coordinates? Please refer to the accompanying image for clarification:

[image]

Comment: This sounds like a verbatim homework question. Is it? 'Optimal' in what sense? In any case, what have you tried? Please post the code you've got and ask a more specific question. Right now this is just a do-it-for-me. As such, it is likely to get closed fairly rapidly. Why the `tikz-pgf` tag if the question is about the 'optimal' method?

Comment: This is no home work. I need this drawing for a specific question for stack-math forum.   I change the tag to #pgfplots

Comment: Honestly, I would just draw an ellipse an neither use any 3D tools or `pgfplots` for this, but just plain Ti*k*Z. For the marked area on the disc, I would use `arc`s with two radii. Everything else is just lines with arrow tips that can be easily be drawn using polar coordinates with two radii. At least, this would the quickest way to achieve this from my point of view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not use any 3D tool or `pgfplots` for this, but just draw this with plain Ti*k*Z using polar coordinates to keep things simple:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    point/.style={
        fill,
        circle,
        inner sep=1pt
    }
}

\newcommand*\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    x={(1cm,0cm)}, 
    y={(0cm,0.5cm)},
    font=\scriptsize,
    >=stealth, 
    pin distance=0.25cm,
    pin position=240,
    every pin edge/.style={
        very thin,
        bend right
    },
    every pin/.append style={
        align=center,
        inner sep=2pt
    }
]

    \draw[->] (0:0) -- (90:4.5) node[right] {$z$};
    \draw[->] (0:0) -- (240:4.5) node[below right] {$y$};
    \draw[->] (0:0) -- (0:4.5) node[below] {$x$};

    \node[point, label={right:$P$}] at (90:3.5) {}; 

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rmeta}{3};

    \draw (0:0) ellipse[radius=\rmeta];
    \draw[->] (0:0) -- (30:\rmeta) node[midway, above] {$R$};

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\alpha}{-35};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\beta}{-65};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rinner}{1};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\router}{2};

    \draw (0:0) -- (\alpha:\rinner);
    \draw (0:0) -- (\beta:\rinner);

    \draw 
        (\beta:0.5) 
        arc[start angle=\beta, end angle=\alpha, radius=0.5];
    \coordinate[pin={$\varphi$}] 
        (a) at ({(\alpha+\beta)/2}:{0.33});

    \draw[thick, fill=red!50] 
        (\beta:\rinner) 
        arc[start angle=\beta, end angle=\alpha, radius=\rinner]
        -- (\alpha:\router) 
        arc[start angle=\alpha, end angle=\beta, radius=\router]
        -- cycle;
    \coordinate[pin={$\diff A =$ \\ $r \cdot \diff y \cdot \diff\varphi$}] 
        (c) at ({(\alpha+\beta)/2}:{(\rinner+\router)/2});

    \draw[<->, shift={(0.15,0.15)}] 
        (\alpha:\rinner) -- ([]\alpha:\router)
        node[pos=0.75, above] {$\diff r$};

    \draw[<->] 
        ([shift={(\alpha:0.15)}]\alpha:\router) 
        arc[start angle=\alpha, end angle=\beta, radius={\router+0.15}]
        node[pos=0.25, below] {$r \cdot \diff y$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks jasper for your effort

Answer (score 3):

Start with this:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Disc with Sector and Point P},
    axis lines = center,
    xlabel = {$x$},
    ylabel = {$y$},
    zlabel = {$z$},
    ticks=none,
    xmin=-1.5, xmax=1.5,
    ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5,
    zmin=0, zmax=2,
    view={120}{25}
]

% Draw the blue outline of the disc
\addplot3[
    samples=50,
    domain=0:360,
    color=blue,
    variable=\t,
] 
({cos(t)}, {sin(t)}, {0});

% Draw a sector in the disc
\addplot3[
    surf,
    domain=35:55,    % Adjust the angle for the desired sector size
    y domain=0:0.8, % Slightly less than the disc radius
    samples=30,
    opacity=0.5,    % Semi-transparent for visibility
] 
({y*cos(x)}, {y*sin(x)}, {0});

% Draw the point P and label it
\addplot3[mark=*, mark options={color=red}] coordinates {(0,0,1.5)};
\node at (axis cs:0,0,1.7) {$P$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks john i will try this also :)